# Understanding the chain rule result and the derivative (spivak)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

In spivak, we have the chain rule result: $D(g\circ f)(a) = Dg(f(a))\circ D(f(a))$

Now, I don't really understand what we are composing here, I tohught $Dg(f(a))$ is a matrix and so is $D(f(a))$ so what are we composing.

Additionally, for this example: Suppose $p(x,y) = xy$ then I have shown that $Dp(x,y)(a,b) = ay+bx$, and for example, if I wanted to calculate $p \circ (log(x),y)$:

$$D(p\circ (log(x),y))(a,b) = Dp(log(x),y)) \circ D(log(x),y)(a,b) = Dp(log(x),y)(1/x,1)(a,b) = Dp(log(x),y)(a/x,b)$$

my question here:

1) Where did the composition go?

2) Why did we multiply $(1/x,1)(a,b)$ to give $(a/x,b)$?

Comment: Maybe considering the matrices as linear maps, one composes them by multiplying.

Comment: Derivatives *are* linear maps, and they must be composed. However, you can identify derivatives and jacobian matrices, and a standard result in linear algebra tells you that composition of linear maps becomes multiplication of their associated matrices.

Comment: Alright thanks, I still don't understand why $(1/x,1)(a,b) = (a/x,b)$ why are we multiplying these exactly?

Comment: Notice that in your displayed equation, you have D(ln x,y)(a,b). That's not right. You're running into inconsistent notation. Really you should have something like D(ln x,y)(x,y)(a,b) - ie, D(name of map)(point evaluated at)(vector applied to). That looks pretty bad, so I advise giving a name, like q, to the map (x,y) \to (\ln x,y). See my answer below.

Comment: And no, Df(a) is not a matrix. It is a linear map. It has an associated matrix of partial derivatives, but that matrix is not the same as the linear map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be helpful to let $q(x,y) = (\ln x ,y).$ Then

$$D(p\circ q)(x,y)(a,b) = (Dp (q(x,y)) \circ Dq (x,y))(a,b) = Dp (q(x,y))\left (Dq (x,y))(a,b)\right ).$$

Now $Dq(x,y)(a,b)= ((1/x)a,b).$ Why? We're not multiplying vectors in some weird way! $Dq(x,y)$ is a linear map from $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R^2.$ That map is given by the associated $2\times 2$ matrix of partial derivatives of $q$ times the column vector $(a,b).$ That matrix has $1/x\,\, 0$ in the first row, $0\,\,1$ in the second row. That's why you get $Dq(x,y)(a,b)= ((1/x)a,b).$

Comment: Thanks that makes a lot more sense - I have just one more question. Why do we apply the derivative to a vector? In the usual 1d case, we evaluate f'(x) at a point x, here we evaluate D(name of map)(point evaluated at) and a (vector applied to), but why the vector applied to

Comment: In 1 d we usually don't view the derivative as a linear mapping. It's just a number. But functions in one variable are differentiable at x in the original sense iff there is a linear map in the new sense. The latter viewpoint has  a natural extension to several variables

Comment: Thanks, I am attempting another example if you don't midn taking a look at that. If not, appreciate all the help!

Comment: @realanalysis In one dimension, a linear map is just multiplication by a constant.